# Why can I not see the actual errormessage in try...catch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, try-catch, sql-server-2019

In a `TRY...CATCH` I am trying to insert the `ERROR_MESSAGE()` into a table but it always gives me the wrong error message. It tells me to look at the previous message. Why?

See the following code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('coolguy.joyhnybravo') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE [coolguy].[joyhnybravo]
 
CREATE TABLE [coolguy].[joyhnybravo]
(
    [hair] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sunglasses] [int] NOT NULL,
)
 
INSERT INTO [coolguy].[joyhnybravo]
select 1,1
union all 
select 1,1
 
SELECT * FROM [coolguy].[joyhnybravo]

BEGIN TRY  
    ALTER TABLE coolguy.joyhnybravo  
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (hair, sunglasses) 
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    SELECT
        GETDATE(), 'ERROR', 'PK (hair, sunglasses) could not be set for coolguy.joyhnybravo 
| STATEMENT: ALTER TABLE coolguy.joyhnybravo ADD PRIMARY KEY (hair, sunglasses)''
| ERROR_NUMBER(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'') AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
| ERROR_SEVERITY(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'') AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
| ERROR_STATE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_STATE(),'') AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
| ERROR_PROCEDURE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') AS SYSNAME) +'
| ERROR_LINE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'') AS VARCHAR(1000)) +'
| ERROR_MESSAGE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'') AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
END CATCH
```

This is what I get :

> () ERROR_MESSAGE(): Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

But this is what I get when executing the statement outside of the try....catch

```
ALTER TABLE coolguy.joyhnybravo 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (hair, sunglasses)
```

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'coolguy.joyhnybravo' and the index name 'PK__joyhnybr__CAF8A5F7EECF20F3'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
> The statement has been terminated.

What I want to catch most is this line:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'coolguy.joyhnybravo' and the index name 'PK__joyhnybr__CAF8A5F7EECF20F3'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).

How to do that?

Comment: You can't get multiple error messages in normal TSQL. You could maybe hack it with `DBCC OUTPUTBUFFER` but it's probably better to either move the error handling to a client app like C# or Powershell, or better: work out why it's erroring in the first place. Eg before you create the key, see if there are any duplicates.

Answer (score -3):

```
Try the below --->
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE  @ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(2048) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    RAISERROR (@ERROR_MESSAGE,16,16)
END CATCH       

OR below way --->
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH       


and then use the select query outside the catch block

 SELECT
        GETDATE(), 'ERROR', 'PK (hair, sunglasses) could not be set for coolguy.joyhnybravo 
| STATEMENT: ALTER TABLE coolguy.joyhnybravo ADD PRIMARY KEY (hair, sunglasses)''
| ERROR_NUMBER(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'') AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
| ERROR_SEVERITY(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'') AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
| ERROR_STATE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_STATE(),'') AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
| ERROR_PROCEDURE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') AS SYSNAME) +'
| ERROR_LINE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'') AS VARCHAR(1000)) +'
| ERROR_MESSAGE(): '+CAST(ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'') AS VARCHAR(1000)) 

Hope this helps!
```